# Replace Product SKU Based on product Title in Order Details Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to append text to the SKU when a sample is ordered.

I have tried the following code to modify the title,

```
  function cart_title($title, $values, $cart_item_key){
          if ($values['sample']){
                  $title .= ' [' . __('Sample','woosample') . '] ';
          }
          return $title;
  }
```

How do I modify this code to change the SKU?

Comment: Does your code not work? What is the resulting `$title` after your code runs?

Comment: @Dan this particular snippet works to change the title. But, I want to modify it to change the SKU in the same way. This returns [Product Name] + Free Sample.

Comment: The full code I am working on is here, https://github.com/isikom/woocommerce-sample/blob/master/woocommerce-sample.php line 187

Answer (score 1):

> note: woocommerce_cart_item_name will not display in the backend order
>   view

```php
function cart_title( $title, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $product = $cart_item['data'];

    $product_sku = $product->get_sku();

    // optional
    if ( empty( $product_sku ) ) {
        $product_sku = 'not found!';
    }

    $title = $title . ' + ' .  $product_sku;
    return $title;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'cart_title', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: This seems to attempt to change the title. I am trying to change the SKU and make sure it also changes in the Order Details page.

Comment: Looks like you missed the question. How do I modify this code to change the SKU?